# Zero divisors of an R ring

Tags: ring-theory

If the cancellation law on the left (respectively, on the right) applies to the product,
so R does not have a zero divisor on the left (resp., on the right). That is true?

Comment: Yes, it’s true. Try to prove it.

Comment: just prove the following motto? Lemma: A ring has a zero divisor on the left (or right) if, and only if, it has a zero divisor.

Comment: I wouldn’t call that a “motto” (“a short sentence encapsulating the ideals or principles guiding an individual, family, or organization”). And what you write is not true, and probably not what you meant. You want to prove that for a ring $R$, $ab=ac, a\neq 0)\implies $b=c$ is equivalent to $xy=0\implies x=0$, and similarly on the right.